# Автоматически развернуть detils в master/details моде

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview, devexpress, table

У меня есть таблица gridControl с двумя gridView соединенных паттерном master/details одним отношением (RelationsCount = 1).

Вопрос очень простой: как сделать автоматическое развертывание (т.е. показать details) при загрузке таблицы ? Другими словами, нужно что бы пользователь при первом просмотре видел уже раскрытую таблицу и ему не приходилось нажимать "+" на каждой строчке.

Посмотрел все свойства, не нашел (возможно плохо искал).

Comment: чтоб не копипастить, см. [в самом низу, Example 3: Expand All Master Rows](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/732/Controls-and-Libraries/Data-Grid/Master-Detail/Working-with-Master-Detail-Relationships-in-Code)

Comment: КМК, стоит заметить, что вместе с "DevExpress" автоматически ставиться "Demo Center" (у меня именно v15.2, в более свежем может быть чуть по другому) в котором для WinForms есть пример "Data Grid and Editors / Master-Detail(Standart)".

Comment: Спасибо! В какой момент лучше вызывать данный метод? Нужно ведь, что бы данные уже были проинициализированы, но еще не выведены пользователю.

Comment: хмм, судя по всему в момент когда *данные уже проинициализированы, но еще не выведены пользователю* :) серьёзно, откуда я могу знать, когда такой момент в вашем приложении наступает?) подсмотрите примеры из ДемоЦентра, и сделайте как вам надо.

Answer (score 1):

Вот решение, если кому то пригодится.

```
public void ExpandAllRows(GridView View)
{
    View.BeginUpdate();
    try
    {
        int dataRowCount = View.DataRowCount;
        for (int rHandle = 0; rHandle < dataRowCount; rHandle++)
            View.SetMasterRowExpanded(rHandle, true);
    }
    finally
    {
        View.EndUpdate();
    }
}
```